# google maps: use directly on google server?

Tags: google-maps

Usually u have to set up a little script + htmlpage on your server to run google maps,
but i was wondering - is it possible to use google maps directly?
i mean by just calling an url with parameters (gpoint coordinates, zoomfactor ..) and it loads the map fullscreen without having to use my own server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like you might be after [the static maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static?csw=1). You can build a URL specifying the properties of the map like:

- zoom
- position
- markers (including custom markers)
- image size
- [etc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static?csw=1#URL_Parameters)

and you will get back a rendered image of the map. Something like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.477222,0&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false))</sub>

Obviously this just gives you a fixed image of the map you are after.  If you need a dynamic Google map, then you will need to use the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?csw=1).

Answer (score 2):

Not hosted by Google. You *might* find some other website that uses the API to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)